# Microservice design : one single call or two separate APIs?

Tags: java, api, microservices

I have a monolithic app that does the following logics:

```
Get a list A (Customer) from database
Validate data in A using some criteria, if it's not validated, throw an error
Do some operations on A to get a list B (e.g. Regional customers)
Do sth with B
```

Now I am transforming my app using microservices, but I have trouble in designing the calls.

As B can be deduced from A entirely, I want to just make a single micro service `getCustomerA` that returns all the dataset A. That means a single database access is needed. That will be a performance plus.

But the problem is, the operations on A to retrieve list B is also **part of the business code**. So it's more logical to put these codes in Customer microservice side, if we follow domain driven design, in microservice `Customer`, maybe `getRegionalCustomer`.

So I want to know, what is the best practice in this case ? Should we priotize the single database call (first case) or it's better to do two calls (but in this case, 2 database calls) ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing some nuance here, but I see a single microservice doing all the steps (other than the database, which of course is its own microservice).

Comment: Hi, yes maybe I am not clear. The validation has to be on main app side because it's related to other domains, i can't put it entirely in Customer microservice

Comment: Think of all the use cases you do or might have in the future. If it doesn't make sense to get Bs without getting As first, then I don't think you need to separate them. But if you want to follow through the idea of **micro** services, then split them. It might look inefficient to make multiple calls for things that could be done at once in a monolithic application but having a clean design is more important in my opinion.

Comment: Which is the logic to get B from A? Maybe you are trying to do your microservice too much micro

Answer (score 3):

Since this is mainly opinion based I can only give you that :-)

From my experience splitting the app into microservices just for the sake of doing it puts technical dogma over technical simplicity and often introduces a lot of unnecessary overhead.

With regard to the database calls I can also tell you from experience that quite often you win performance when doing two simple calls over doing one overly complex one. Especially if you start introducing big joins over many tables or - ouch - subselects in the `on` clause.

See if the most simple solution works and keeps the code tidy. Constantly improve quality and optimize when the need for it arises. If you have a piece of logic that warrants to be split of into a microservice (e.g. because you want to use a different language, framework or want to offload some calculations) then go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Domain driven design does not tell that each boundle context only can contains one entity, in fact, a bounded context (or microservice) can contains more than one entity when these entites are clearly related, in other words, when they need to be persisted transactionally.

In your case, due to the tight relation between the two entites, the best way is to build only one microservice that do both operations